# Convert vtkPoints to numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, vtk

I am using Mayavi2 in a Python script to calculate 3d iso-surfaces. As a result I get a vtkPoints object. Now I want to convert this vtkPoints object ('vtkout' in the code sample below) to a simple numpy array with 3 lines containing all x, y and z values.
I get vtkout using a code like this:

```
import numpy
from enthought.mayavi import mlab
import array

randVol = numpy.random.rand(50,50,50)        # fill volume with some random potential
X, Y, Z = numpy.mgrid[0:50, 0:50, 0:50]      # grid
surf = mlab.contour3d(X, Y, Z, randVol, contours=[0.5])   # calc contour
vtkout = surf.contour.contour_filter.output.points        # get the vtkPoints object
```

At the moment I use the following code to extract the points into an array:

```
pointsArray = numpy.zeros((3, vtkout.number_of_points))
for n in range(vtkout.number_of_points):
    pointsArray[0,n] = vtkout[n][0]
    pointsArray[1,n] = vtkout[n][1]
    pointsArray[2,n] = vtkout[n][2]
```

I wonder if there is no general routine doing such conversions for me in a convenient, fast and safe way?

Comment: I don't know the Python interface of VTK, but if you are lucky, they properly used Python's buffer interface.  Try something like `numpy.frombuffer(vtkout)` and reshape after this.

Comment: like Sven, I'm not familiar with the interface, but a little googling indicated (if I got the correct interface -- I tried to find number_of_points), that you might be able to use `vtkout.to_array()`. If you provide a short example with the proper import statements to generate a sample vtkPoints object, I could probably help you further.

Comment: @JoshAdel: Many thanks, of course you are right! I read something about the `to_array()` method, but somehow did not use it properly. Now I tried it again and it works perfectly!
`pointsArray = vtkout.to_array().T` does the job. If you want you could add this as an answer, so that I can give you proper credits ;).

@Sven: I also tried your suggestion, but unfortunately, the buffer interface is _not_ implemented. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I tried the same, but am receiving an error: "AttributeError: to_array" in python. Do you remember the vtk version you were using or have an idea, why this doesn't work for me? Maybe it has something to do with Mayavi2? Do you know if this should work with regular vtk python bindings?

Comment: @Chris: Are you sure you wrote `to_array()`? (do not forget the brackets!)

Comment: @JakobS. sorry, I only now stumbled across this question again. Yes, I wrote it with brackets, but I am still seeing the same error :D in the end I copied the points into the numpy array "manually" (similar to your initial suggestion).

Comment: @Chris I also have the same problem - its very frustrating. What version of paraview do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed from comments on the original post, you might try:

```
vtkout.to_array().T
```

This is a direct method that does not require looping.

Comment: Im unable to use this method on my `vtkPoints` object (`AttributeError: to_array`). Any ideas?

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore. See Fabio Zadrozny's answer that works for vtk8.x

Answer (score 8):

`vtk_points.to_array()` did not work for me (to_array() doesn't seem to exist in plain vtk).

What has actually worked in my case is using the `numpy_support` module:

```
from vtk.util import numpy_support
as_numpy = numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(vtk_points.GetData())
```